# Liferay WorkFlow with Kaleo : use custom class on task

Tags: java, groovy, liferay, workflow

I'm working with Kaleo Designer.

[image]

As you can see into image : "import com.MYPACKAGE.MYCUSTOMCLASS".

Is possible to import a custom java class and call my custom methods in kaleo designer actions?

Comment: Please at least reference your crosspostings, so that others have the possibility to check if the question is already answered elsewhere. 

https://www.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/55643940

Comment: I have created this question on liferay forum and on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically yes, however some of the work needs to be done. You need to extend default BeanLocator to inject your custom classes which will be used as services. Then you will be able to use them either in workflow script or web content templates.

Follow instructions in this tutorial to achieve your goal. I found it very usefull in my case. https://www.liferay.com/web/pmesotten/blog/-/blogs/inject-any-custom-class-or-service-into-web-content-templates